# JAVA - Object cannot be added to Object Array - NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I am initializing an Object(Bateau), which contains within it an array of objects (Element) called elements.

Upon calling the constructor, I want to create several elements for a "bateau" object.

The number of elements vary depending on which kind of "bateau" it is because "Bateau" has 3 sub-classes which determine the number of elements to initialize.

I get a NPE when I try to add a new Element to elements, can anyone help me resolve this issue ?

```
public class Bateau {
private boolean horizontal = false;
protected Element[] elements;

public Bateau(int pX, int pY, boolean horizontal, int nombreElements) {
    this.horizontal = horizontal;
    for (int i = 0; i < nombreElements; i++) {
        if (this.horizontal) {
            //NullPointerException elements[i] not initialized ?
            this.elements[i] = new Element((pX + i), pY);
        } else {
            this.elements[i] = new Element(pX, (pY + i));

        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: where do you think the array initialization occurs? some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761646/initialize-java-array-vs-other-initialization

Comment: I added: elements = new Element[nombreElements]; in my constructor.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/27180473/573032

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your debugger you would be able to see that

```
Element[] elements = null;
```

I suggest you initialise it with

```
elements = new Element[nombreElements];
```